# How do I keep websocket alive while I am processing data?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket

I am connecting a websocket server and request data from it, the problem I am facing is the following:

1. the websocket server sends me a message every 10s, and I must reply as soon as I get that message.
2. When I process the received data from server, I need much more than 10s, let's say I need about 5 min to process each data received.
3. I have a loop, the loop does: first receive data from websocket connection, then process in local computers(which takes time), send another request and receive new data from websocket connection and so on.

I want to keep websocket connection alive but the interval I need to reply to the server is about 10s which is much shorter than the time I need to process the data, how can I do?

The following psuedo-code explain the above statement:

```
import websocket 
import time

ws = websocket.WebSocket() 
ws.connect("wss://example.com")


def keep_alive():
    # this is what I need to interact to keep the connection on
    while True:
        data_recvd = ws.recv()  # suppose the received data is always an integer
        if data_recvd > 1000:
            ws.send(data_recvd)


def process_data(data):
    # suppose the processing takes very long time
    print(data)
    time.sleep(300)
    pass


for i in range(100):
    ws.send("message %d" % i)
    data = ws.recv()
    if data < 1000:
        process_data(data)  # if I write the program like this, the connection will be lost.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your pseudo-code is bit more complex than it should be. I will write my version of solving this problem using JavaScript(and you have to specify port).

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com:80");
ws.onMessage = function(event){
   ws.send("Hello, server");
   executeAsync(longFunction());       
}
function longFunction(){
//timeout 5 min
}
```

All you need to do, is to create a new Thread(run your long function async). When longFunction is done, thread closing and you back to infinite loop(in my code snippet, ws.onMessage listen server messages infinite). But after some time you will have threads as much as server sent messages, so, be carefully with creating threads.